# Why array's equals() isn't overridden as in Arrays.equals()

Tags: java, arrays, language-design

I understand that array's `equals()` is in effect `Object.equals()` and pratically no one should use it (just use `==` and avoid NPE), instead they should use `Arrays.equals()` if they are not comparing for identity.

So why didn't Java just make the `equals()` method of an array overridden as in `Arrays.equals()`? This would save a lot of unexpected behavior for beginners and make some use of arrays easier (such as in a `Set`), while I cannot think of any drawback. Or is there any reason that prevented the language from doing so?

Comment: Note that `array`s are very **old**. The `Arrays` class came with **1.2** which is afterwards (also where `Collections` was introduced, with similar `equals` methods). I don't know if there was a specific reason but it could be possible that they simply didn't thought of it and later didn't want to change it to ensure backwards compatibility and instead created `Arrays#equals`.

Comment: Java is all about compatibility with older versions. If you look at the existence of classes like `java.util.Vector` you get a very good example for that. Another example is that `Properties` is still returning objects and instead introduced `getProperty` to return a string. If you are looking for a modern version of Java, I could recommend looking at Kotlin, which defaults the `==` operator to the `equals` method (plus many other cool features)

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/239139

Comment: @PaulBoddington I just read that question (wasn't on stackoverflow so didn't find it), but the accepted answer didn't really answer the question. It mentioned arrays are related to primitives, but didn't say why giving an `equals()` implementation that is different from `Object.equals()` is not feasible. Logically, it is not because arrays are at memory level because Java already made array a subclass of `Object`. And it is not about holding primitives because Java containers are unable to hold primitives due to generics instead of difficulty in handling primitives.

Comment: @msrd0 If it is about backward-compatibility, is there any official documentation or reference clearing stating this? (because I didn't find any)

Comment: Well, documentation is usually about the behaviour of the code right now, not about the reasons why nobody changes the behaviour. However, I don't know about any java class that is used as a base for every array (although arrays have properties and methods like `length`), so I don't know where to search for documentation